# .click will not work with onclick="this.classlist.toggle('')"

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand why when I click the button, the annimation does not begin. If the coin is clicked manually, it works fine. The button is hooked to a onclick function that should then click the coin to begin the annimation. Responses are VERY much appreciated. I have spent the past 4 hours trying to figure this out and have made no progress. Thanks!

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Studdier/wxedtf0x/16/

```js
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("coin").click();
}
```

```css
#hero {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.teamlogo{
padding-left:5%;
}
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container{
/*perspective*/
-webkit-perspective:1000;
   -moz-perspective:1000;
    -ms-perspective:1000;
     -o-perspective:1000;
        perspective:1000;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
  .flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container, .front, .back{
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper{
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:5s;
   -moz-transition:5s;
     -o-transition:5s;
        transition:5s;
/*transform-style*/
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
position:relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back{
/*backface-visibility*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */
.front{
z-index:2;
}
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back{
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
<div class="flipper" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped')" id="transition">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VIUd498.png" id="coin">
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OoSnP5t.png" class="inactiveLink">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="tails" value=" button " id = "hero" onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```

Comment: understand what clicking an `<input type="submit" >` element in a form does ... hint: submits the form and loads a new (or reloads the current) page - it never ceases to amaze me why people abuse `forms` like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the type of the input from "submit" to "button". That'll prevent it from submitting the form to the server.

```js
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("coin").click();
}
```

```css
#hero {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.teamlogo{
padding-left:5%;
}
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container{
/*perspective*/
-webkit-perspective:1000;
   -moz-perspective:1000;
    -ms-perspective:1000;
     -o-perspective:1000;
        perspective:1000;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
  .flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-container, .front, .back{
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper{
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:5s;
   -moz-transition:5s;
     -o-transition:5s;
        transition:5s;
/*transform-style*/
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
position:relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back{
/*backface-visibility*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
/* front pane, placed above back */
.front{
z-index:2;
}
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back{
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
<div class="flipper" onclick="this.classList.toggle('flipped')" id="transition">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/VIUd498.png" id="coin">
    </div>

    <div class="back">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OoSnP5t.png" class="inactiveLink">
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="button" name="tails" value=" button " id = "hero" onclick="myFunction()" />
</form>
```